# Access a USB printer from a Win7 PC hardwired to router from laptop connected to wifi from same router?

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer, domain, sharing

Here is a summary of my issue.
I have a Dot matrix printer attached to a win7 home edition computer, shared with another Win7 home edition over a workgroup.  Those computers are wired directly to the router providing internet service.
Also throughout the office are laptops connected to same router wirelessly connected to a domain hosted on a server down the road.
What I would like to achieve is be able to share the dot matrix printer with both the workgroup printers and the domain computers, while being able to stay connected to domain on the laptops.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: How is this not a simple Google question? What have you tried? What issues are you having? This is a Q&A format, not a tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, because all computers are connected to the same router, they can access each other as long as they are set on the same network segment.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. Turn on file and printer sharing, and share the printer.

Caveat The computer has to be ON for the shared printer to be accessed.

**Make sure your firewall doesn't block the necessary ports or your going nowhere fast.**

Filling the share name provided when you turned on file and printer sharing.

[image: Add Printer Dialog]

2. Buy an external print server that hosts an IP address, then computer can be turned off.

Caveat  You have to buy a [print server](https://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=ethernet%20to%20usb%20print%20server&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=229116137029&hvpos=1t1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=15309484026810114089&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9018840&hvtargid=kwd-300032921445&ref=pd_sl_2csv1o4rkf_b_p38).